# Python - Django - Filter and count all people in first year from start date

Tags: python, django, count

I need to count all the people who are in the first year of the contract.
I even made several attempts and failed. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Model:

```
class Contracts(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Name')
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='Start')

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.person)
```

So far...

View:

```
def people_in_first_year(request):
    people = Contracts.objects.filter(Q(start_date__lte=timezone.now()) & Q(end_date__gte=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=365)))
    total_people = people.count()

    context = {
        'total_people': total_people,
    }

    return render(request, 'people.html', context)
```

Comment: Does your model have a end date? If so please add it to code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is not an `end_date`, you can not filter much on that one. What you can do is simply set the `start_date` to be greater than or equal to now minus 365 days:

```
total_people = Contracts.objects.filter(
    start_date__gte=timezone.now() - timedelta(days=365)
).count()
```

A year however is not per se 365 days. You can for example make use of the [**`python-dateutil`** package [pypi]](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/), and work with a [**`relativedelta`** [readthedocs.io]](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html):

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

total_people = Contracts.objects.filter(
    start_date__gte=timezone.now() - relativedelta(years=1)
).count()
```

Comment: Thank you! It's perfect!